# Text change on UIButton doesn't stick

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ipad, interface-builder, uibutton

I have an UIButton in my View that says "STOP". When pressed, it should (stop the playback, of course, and) change its label to "RTN TO ZERO". This is straightforward:

`stopButton.titleLabel.text = @"RTN TO ZERO";`

However, the change appears only for a split second. It doesn't stick. I assume that the button (which gets highlighted when pressed) accepts and displays the new label, but somehow the highlight is reversed only later, restoring the button to the look it had before it was pressed, not honoring the label text change.
The button is conceived in IB, not programmatically.

I feel stupid. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Which events do you have the code to change the title in?  Could you provide some more detail?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In the button handler, try this:

```
[stopButton setTitle:@"RTN TO ZERO" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Instead of directly changing `text` property of `titleLabel` use `setTitle:forState:` method to set the title in different states. Please check the [manual](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton) for the details of available states.

Comment: You're right. Reading ability IS an advantage. As I said, I feel stupid. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just as a side-note; this approach does not work if you are using attributed text in IB. You have to use setAttributedTitle:forState:.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift version**

```
myButton.setTitle("button text", for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

Use `setAttributedTitle:for` for attributed text. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32269975/3681880) for how to make attributed strings in Swift.